# I receive an id of a Role and with that id I list all the permissions that are assigned to that role

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

Good Evening, it is possible that in SPATIE-LARAVEL-PERMISSION the following:

Some function or way that I receive an id of a Role and with that id I list all the permissions that are assigned to that role. I'm looking but I didn't find an answer. sorry for the inconvenience thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/role-permissions#content-what-permissions-does-a-role-have) in the docs, you can get all permissions of a role with the `permissions` relation

```php
use \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

Role::find($id)->permissions;
```